# EXCEL : move/copy/delete data (conditional) from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

My task is the following:

1. **Move Data From Sheet-1 To Sheet-2** (condition :  Which Data from
   Column A , Start With 88017) (or)
2. **Copy Data From Sheet-1 To Sheet-2** (condition :  Which Data from
   Column A , Start With 88017)  (or)
3. **Delete Data From Sheet-1** (condition :  Which Data from Column A ,
   Start With 88017)

   ```
   Sheet 1 :                             Sheet 2 : (result)
              A | B                             A | B
   Phone Number | Name               Phone Number | Name
   88017605020  | ABCD               88017605020    | ABCD
   88018605020  | EFGH               88017605020    | IJKL
   88017605020  | IJKL               88017605020    | MNOP
   88017605020  | MNOP               88017605020    | UVWX
   88016605020  | QRST               88017605020    | ASDD
   88017605020  | UVWX
   88015605020  | YZA
   88017605020  | ASDD
   88016605020  | DEED
   ```

How can I do this in Excel?

Comment: Conditions are the same for 3 different tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You can copy, mark, then delete using the below.

```
public sub CopyRowsToSheet2()
  dim sws as worksheet
  dim tws as worksheet
  dim aCell as range
  dim lRow as long
  lrow = 2
  with thisworkbook
    set sws = .sheets("Sheet1")
    set tws = .sheets("Sheet2")
    for each acell in intersect(sws.usedrange, sws.Range("A1").entirecolumn)
      if acell.value = "88017605020" then
        acell.entirerow.copy tws.Range("A" & lRow)
        acell.value = "XXXX"    'Mark to later delete
        lrow = lrow + 1
      endif
    next acell
   'Loop bottom to top to delete marked rows.
   for lrow = sws.usedrange.rows.count to 1 step -1
      if acell.value = "xxxx" then
        sws.range("A" & lrow).delete
      endif
    next lrow
exit sub
```

Comment: Remember to mark the answer to help others locate the best answer more quickly.