# How do I copy filtered data from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create VBA do perform create the report from HTML file. I converted the HTML to excel using a python script. Now I want to filter the data of module M1 from excel sheet 1 and move the filtered data to sheet 2. I will do the same for all modules.

I did the filtering using below function (button)

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim SampleString As String
SampleString = Range("D1").Value
'MsgBox SampleString

Sheet1.Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter

Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="*E2E*"
Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="*Adv*"


End Sub
```

Now I want to move this filter data to sheet 2. How do I copy filtered data and paste to sheet 2?

Referred [SE Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29494376/excel-move-copy-delete-data-conditional-from-one-sheet-to-another)

Comment: Move or Copy? That make a huge difference. Please be precise and [edit] your question accordingly. If you mean copy: Did you try to record a macro to see how the code could look like?

Comment: Thank you, I got the details after recording the macro.